# Convert VKCode to String Java

Tags: java, hashmap, virtual-keyboard

As the title suggests I want to convert a string to VK code, my original idea was to have:

```java
HashMap<char,(what)> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put('A',KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

And do that for all the values then loop through the string but I don't know if anything like that is possible.

Is the best way just to have a switch for every character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VK` constants appear to be ints, so you should just have a `Map<Character, Integer>`.

Alternately, you could use [`getExtendedKeyCodeForChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int)), passing in the `char`, to get the key code.